# Sort by an ID column and date column (MM/DD/YYYY)

Tags: bash, sorting, unix

I'm trying to sort a .txt file by both an ID column and a date column, but the date sort part is not working as I need it to.

Data:

```
|855986|03/01/1980|100|
|855986|06/01/1979|120|
|868566|01/01/1999|560|
|855986|05/01/2015|856|
|868566|09/01/2000|560|
```

What I need output to look like:

```
|855986|06/01/1979|120|
|855986|03/01/1980|100|
|855986|05/01/2015|856|
|868566|01/01/1999|560|
|868566|09/01/2000|560|
```

Here's my current code, which sorts the ID and month correctly, but seems to ignore the year portion of the date:

```
sort -t '|' -k 1 -b -k 2.7,2.10 -k 2.1,2.2 file.txt
```

Comment: do you want 2015 to be in the middle?  What is the ordering logic?

Answer (score 3):

You are pretty close. However date field is actually field #3 as `|` is first character in every line.

You can use:

```
sort -b -t '|' -k 3.7,3.10 -k 3.4,3.5 -k 3.1,3.2 file
|855986|06/01/1979|120|
|855986|03/01/1980|100|
|868566|01/01/1999|560|
|868566|09/01/2000|560|
|855986|05/01/2015|856|
```